# How to show mathematically that random effects are more efficient than fixed effects?

Tags: mixed-model, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, efficiency

I have read in several places now that random effects estimators are more efficient than fixed effects estimators, in particular [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238214/how-exactly-does-a-random-effects-model-in-econometrics-relate-to-mixed-models)

I’ve searched this site and Google and couldn’t find this result. So I’m still not sure how to show this.

Thanks